# another way for proof of Continuity of translation on $L^{1}$ on the reals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued, Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$. prove

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+t)-f(x)|\, dx=0.$$

I solved it in this way. is it correct?

Since $f$ is integrable, given $\epsilon>0$, there is a continuous function $h$ vanishing outside a finite integral $[a,b]$ such that $\int \left|f(x)-h(x)\right|dx<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Then
$\int \left|f(x)-f(x+t)\right|dx \leq \int \left|h(x)-h(x+t)\right|dx + \int \left|(f-h)(x)-(f-h)(x+t)\right|dx$.
Now since $h$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$\left|h(x)-h(x+t)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}(b-a)$ whenever $\left|t\right|<\delta$. Thus 
$\int \left|f(x)-f(x+t)\right|dx \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \int \left|f(x)-h(x)\right|dx + \int \left|(f-h)(x)\right|dx+ \int \left|(f-h)(x+t)\right|dx= \frac{\epsilon}{2} +2 \int \left|f(x)-h(x)\right|dx\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} +2\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

Comment: Its correct and you can also you a similar density argument known as "three - epsilon" to show the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $\epsilon/(2(b-a))$ instead of $\epsilon(b-a)/2$.

There are also some other small imprecisions (e.g. $\epsilon/2 +2\cdot \epsilon/2\neq \epsilon$).

Finally, uniform continuity of $h$ on $[a,b]$ strictly speaking only gives that $|h(x+t)-h(x)|$ is small if $|t|$ is small **and** $x,x+t\in [a,b]$. You have to work a bit (but not much) to fix this.

Apart from these things, your proof is fine.